# How to install bokeh for Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, bokeh, pypi

I installed bokeh via pip and here is the information of the versions that are installed

```
pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.5.2
pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.12
pooja@X1-Carbon-6:~$ bokeh --version
0.13.0
```

for python2, it works fine and could import bokeh

```
lkhr@X1-Carbon-6:~notebooks$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bokeh
>>>
```

However, it complains when I use python3

```
olkhr@X1-Carbon-6:~$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bokeh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'bokeh'
>>>
```

I want to use bokeh in my *Python3 Jupyter-Notebook* and having problem cos of this, if any suggestions are available, please let me know.

Many thanks,

Comment: I could install bokeh on virtual python3 environment, could do 'bokeh import' in python3, but still fail to import it in python3 jupyter-notebook, when opened in python3 virtual environment.  (disappointed)

Comment: I posted an answer, hope help you up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will sound trivial but you need to install both (jupyter notebook and bokeh) under the same environment (virtual or not).

If you installed jupyter notebook using a snippet from the [jupyter's website](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) (`pip3 install jupyter`) then you have it installed in a non-virtual environment and from what I've understood you are trying to import bokeh which is installed in a virtual one.

There are two solutions:

1. You run everything under **non-virtual** environment (*which is probably not the best/cleanest choice*):

   - install the notebook using `pip3 install jupyter`
   - install bokeh using `pip3 install bokeh`
   - start the notebook using `jupyter notebook` (*without activating virtual environment*)
2. You run everything under **virtual** environment:

   - activate your virtual environment
   - install the notebook using `python -m pip install jupyter`
   - install bokeh using `python -m pip install bokeh`
   - start the notebook using `jupyter notebook`

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here. 
Apparently, there are some problems with `pip` installation.
I solved my problem with re-installing `bokeh` with `conda`.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experiences. I am personally not a big fan of conda cos of my past experiences. So would like to have things working without conda. Lets see, if I succeed or would have to give Conda a try again. thanks again!

Comment: @Pooja If you succeed, please let us know how. Thank you.

Comment: @Pooja I'd encourage you to look at conda again. All conda environments are completely self-contained and don't touch the system or other Python at all, which is a great feature for safety and reproducibility. Additionally many of the packages shipped with conda are more optimized (e.g. NumPy ships with Intel MKL linked)

Answer (score 1):

You can have both versions of `pip` together (`pip2`, `pip3`).

Also `pip` can be linked to whether `pip2/python2` or `pip3/python3`.

For me, `pip` is linked to the *Python 3.x*, `pip2` to the *Python 2.7* and `pip3` to the *Python 3.x*:

```
$ pip -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip-9.0.3-py3.6.egg (python 3.6)

$ pip2 -V
pip 10.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

$ pip3 -V
pip 9.0.3 from /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pip-9.0.3-py3.6.egg (python 3.6)
```

---

#### Python versions:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.12

$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.6
```

---

In this case, you should install **bokeh** for both versions of Python:

```
pip3 install bokeh
pip2 install bokeh
```

---

## Test:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bokeh
>>> 

$ python3
Python 3.6.6 (default, Jun 28 2018, 04:42:43) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bokeh
>>>
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

Refer to the following links to install both versions of `pip`:

- [Link_1](https://askubuntu.com/a/879034/772449)
- [Link_2](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu-18.04/)